# Yii 1 how to revert all migrations

Tags: php, yii, migration

I wonder if I can revert all migrations in a folder without counting them and then inserting that number as param.

I need something like that:

```
yiic migrate down -all
```

Answer (score 1):

framework/cli/command/MigrateCommand.php

```
...
    public function actionDown($args)
    {
        $step=isset($args[0]) ? (int)$args[0] : 1;
        if($step<1)
        {
            echo "Error: The step parameter must be greater than 0.\n";
            return 1;
        }
...
```

You have 2 choice: 
 1. use hack like yiic migrate down 9999;
 2. extend MigrateCOmmand class and implemet this option.

Comment: There is a 3d option to count files

Comment: Or get count from table tbl_migrations.